# Is there a way to use jinja template in combination with the DatabricksSubmitRunOperator in Airflow?

Tags: jinja2, databricks, airflow

I am currently working with the DatabricksSubmitRunOperator in Airflow. When I tried to integrate the jinja template into the operator, by using it in the "json"-parameter of the operator, I was facing an error. The problem is, that jinja returns a string but Databricks operator needs a dict type.

I already looked up the source code of the operator. "json" seems to be a template_field, which should be fine.

Is there a way to make jinja return a dict type instead of a string in this case? Or maybe another workaround?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is the new feature in Airflow 2.1/0 that can help with that https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/operators.html#rendering-fields-as-native-python-objects - it uses JINJA capability of "safe evaluation" of the string and returning and object that the string represents directly in your code.

Comment: I guess that already solved it, thank you!